# Raspberry Pi 3 not detected by pc

Tags: pi-3

I'm a total noob to the Raspberry Pi. I plugged in the SD card, a network cable and then plugged it into my pc with the mini-USB cable.

Now the little led is going red, but I can't find the drive anywhere on my pc.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting close!!!!

That USB you have plugged into your computer needs to actually be plugged into a phone charger. RPI foundation recommends that
you use a 2.5A (2500 ma) power supply. You can get away with a 1A (1000ma) supply but dont plug more than a keybaord and mouse in. - check out a video named 
`Pi 3 power tests! @Raspberry_Pi #raspberrypi #pi3 #deskofladyada @adafruit 3/5/2016` on youtube.

So you need to have an OS (Operating System) installed on the card. [see NOOBS guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/)

Not to be a jerk, but this link will get you right where you want to be.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/hardware-guide/
There site is great! It has all the information you're looking for! Good luck! They even have simple projects to get you started with code examples.

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi is a computer, just like your PC.

The mini-USB cable will provide power.

You need to login to the Pi via the network cable.

Perhaps use putty or similar to connect to the network machine called raspberrypi?

The default login name will be pi and the default password will be raspberry.

Comment: How do I connect? I found an unknown IP address, put it in Putty and it timed out.

Comment: You need to add details to your question.  In particular the Pi boots from the SD card.  What image have you written to the card or came pre-installed with the card.

Answer (score 0):

The micro-USB socket on the Pi has no data pins and is for powering only, it is incapable of any form of data.

NOTE A standards compliant USB port on a PC should not supply sufficient current to run the Pi, although many are non-compliant and will provide power, but this is still unlikely to be sufficient for reliable performance. You need at least a 1A power supply for basic operation, more for any peripherals.